# Font Awesome - When stacking icons can I divide instead of multiply?

Tags: css, font-awesome

When stacking icons can I divide instead of multiply? I want my first icon to be the same size as the font I am using and the icon on-top of it to be the font size divided by 2. Is this possible with what comes with Font Awesome or do I need to create this feature from scratch?

**What I have now:**

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

**What I want:**

```
<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-2/"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new class

```
fa-stack-half {
    font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.fa` class ex check [**font-Awesome**](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/)

check under Fixed Width Icons

```
<div class="list-group">
   <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Home</a>
</div>
```